# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am accessing data from another component using `props` but its says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
```

anyone knows how to solve

```
function AuditDetails(props)
{ 

function AuditDetails(props) {
let data=props.location.state;
data=data.data;
console.log("data",data);
  
}  

 and this the function from where I am getting the data

 const onRowClick = (data, columns) => {
    return {
        onClick: e => {
            console.log('clicked')
            console.log('it produced this event:', e)
            console.log('Columns:', columns)
            console.log('Data:', columns.original)
            history.push("/AuditDetails",{data:columns.original})
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like props.location.state is null, and then you are trying to get the field "data" from a null value. Can you see if props.location is returning what you expect it to?

Comment: when I see data in console some times it shows data sometimes it gives error

Comment: please show result of console.log('Data:', columns.original)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `optional chaining` to avoid errors like this. `data=data?.data;`

Because only when you call `onRowClick` and redirect to `/AuditDetails`, it has state with `data`. If you redirect by click link in the navbar , it will not have state, so `props.location.state` will return null

Comment: Tried this i also have a navbar in the top but there isn't any connection with it when i click any link in the navbar it shows this error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data'

Comment: You need to update more code. With current infor, I just know this solution.

Comment: please show result of console.log('Data:', columns.original)

Comment: address: "9 road"
assignee: "sibas"
audit_name: "riba"
contact_person: "mike"
created_by: "Admin"
created_date: "04/02/2021"
phone: "5654589632"
start_date: "26/01/2021"

Comment: This the output of this

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
history.push({path:"/AuditDetails", state:{data:columns.original})
```

on the onRowClick function.

Comment: have you checked if columns is not null before pushing? are you using react hooks?

Comment: yes in the console columns are showing but if i click in navbar or some thing it says errors like this although it does not have any connection with navbar no I ma using react router dom

Comment: try adding the keyword this before props, i'm not used to legacy code but you probably need something like: this.props.location.state